# Uppercasing first letters of words using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to turn names that are always in lower case into uppercase.

e.g. `john johnsson` -> `John Johnsson`

but also:

`jonny-bart johnsson` -> `Jonny-Bart Johnsson`

How do I accomplish this using PHP?

Answer (score 6):

You could also use a regular expression:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\b\p{Ll}/', 'callback', $str)
```

`\b` represents a word boundary and `\p{Ll}` describes any lowercase letter in Unicode. [`preg_replace_callback`](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) will call a function called `callback` for each match and replace the match with its return value:

```
function callback($match) {
    return mb_strtoupper($match[0]);
}
```

Here [`mb_strtoupper`](http://php.net/mb_strtoupper) is used to turn the matched lowercase letter to uppercase.

Comment: I like this one, but I think there is a danger to advocating the /e modifier on public forums like these, where unexperienced programmers will not see the clear dangers of it.

Comment: @mvds: I changed it to use `preg_replace_callback` instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you're expecting unicode characters...or even if you're not, I recommend using [mb_convert_case](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-case.php) nonetheless. You shouldn't need to use preg_replace when there's a php function for this.

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
//FUNCTION

function ucname($string) {
    $string =ucwords(strtolower($string));

    foreach (array('-', '\'') as $delimiter) {
      if (strpos($string, $delimiter)!==false) {
        $string =implode($delimiter, array_map('ucfirst', explode($delimiter, $string)));
      }
    }
    return $string;
}
?>
<?php
//TEST

$names =array(
  'JEAN-LUC PICARD',
  'MILES O\'BRIEN',
  'WILLIAM RIKER',
  'geordi la forge',
  'bEvErly CRuSHeR'
);
foreach ($names as $name) { print ucname("{$name}\n"); }

//PRINTS:
/*
Jean-Luc Picard
Miles O'Brien
William Riker
Geordi La Forge
Beverly Crusher
*/
?>
```

From comments on the PHP manual entry for [`ucwords`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php#96179).

Comment: Note that this initially lowercases the whole string, which may or may not be what you want - you can always remove the `strtolower` call if it's not what you want.

Answer (score 1):

with regexps:

```
$out = preg_replace_callback("/[a-z]+/i",'ucfirst_match',$in);

function ucfirst_match($match)
{
    return ucfirst(strtolower($match[0]));
}
```

Comment: i would use a `preg_replace_callback` was coming on here to write this but beat me to it.. +1

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I came up with (tested)...

```
$chars="'";//characters other than space and dash
           //after which letters should be capitalized

function callback($matches){
    return $matches[1].strtoupper($matches[2]);
}

$name="john doe";
$name=preg_replace_callback('/(^|[ \-'.$chars.'])([a-z])/',"callback",$name);
```

Or if you have php 5.3+ this is probably better (untested):

```
function capitalizeName($name,$chars="'"){
    return preg_replace_callback('/(^|[ \-'.$chars.'])([a-z])/',
        function($matches){
            return $matches[1].strtoupper($matches[2]);
        },$name);
}
```

My solution is a bit more verbose than some of the others posted, but I believe it offers the best flexibility (you can modify the `$chars` string to change which characters can separate names).